# Why I get wrong bytes when a read a binary file in python?

Tags: python, printing, type-conversion, binaryfiles

I have a binary file which begin with (in hex view) : 00 09 0f **c3 b0**

I open a file in python and then read and print it and the result is different only for some bytes: 00 09 0f **f0 0f**

```
f = open(filename, "rb")
data = f.read()
        print(data)
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Your code is printing the raw data that it read, but you're showing us hex bytes. You're leaving something out. Please elaborate on exactly how you're testing this.

Comment: Could you add the output from `xxd -p script.py | head -n 1`

Comment: I'm adding "data" variable in variable called "payload" which is defined like this 
payload = bytearray() 
I have a for loop for the data variable : 
for c in data:
    payload.append(c)

This payload goes in a UDP packet and I can read in wireshark the same data that it was print before

Comment: You've omitted a lot of relevant information such as python version, OS, and locale (codepage if on Windows).